# How do I make a label move onclick?

Tags: java, object, netbeans, event-handling, label

I'm doing a object orientated programming project for college and for my part all I need to do is to be able to make a 1d game character move a step forward every time the next button is clicked by the user.  I am using Netbeans and have created a JLabel to use as the character and we have the button made but I have no clue where to start when it comes to actually having the event happen.

Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an `ActionListener`to your next button. As soon as you click your button, the actionListener's `actionPerformed` method will be called in which you can process the event handling. (see [How to Write an ActionListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for further information).

In order to move your label I recommend setting the layout for your label's container to null (see [Using Layout Managers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)) and specifying the position manually. In your actionPerformed Method you can then set the label's position to a different value.

In order to be able to control your label's position you have to make use of three core operations:

- `container.setLayout(null);` (for the container component holding your label
- `label.addActionListener(myActionListener);` to add the ActionListener to your label
- `label.setLocation(newX, Y);` to move your label component (needs to be performed in your actionPerformed-method)